# how to plot location details in map in android application without web api's

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a **GPS technology**  based project, In this project we have **GPS device** which log the location details to **SQL server DB** in every 10 seconds.In android app ,Currently i am calling **web API's** method in timer event to clot the location details in map for some particular interval. So i want eliminate this timer and i want to clot the location details whenever device pushes the log data. So how can we achieve it in android app

Comment: Create a simple Async task or Service which run in the background.
Call the API every 10 sec and get the lat-lang from your web server.Using Google map you can display the location details

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil Instead of this is there any way to updated the location once device  data has inserted to SQL Database?

Comment: Android App need location data to display on map..this location data can come through the API only.

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil Can we use firebase realtime database concepts here to update location details

Comment: Yes you can use Realtime database or you can try Apache Kafka